# Performance with thread pooling in OpenMP

Tags: openmp

I have following code:

```
float arr[1000];
for(int j=0; j<1000; ++j)
{
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(t1)
  {
    #pragma omp for
    for(int i=0; i<1000; ++i) arr[i] = std::pow(i,2);
  }
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(t2)
  {
    #pragma omp for
    for(int i=0; i<1000; ++i) arr[i] = std::pow(i,2);
  }
}
```

- for t1=1, t2=36 time is 160
- for t1=2, t2=36 time is 3800
- for t1=8, t2=36 time is 2020
- for t1=18, t2=36 time is 1370
- for t1=24, t2=36 time is 880
- for t1=30, t2=36 time is 450
- for t1=36, t2=36 time is 146

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v3 @ 2.30GHz, cores per socket: 18, virtualization: VT-x, sockets: 2, L1d cache: 32K, L1i cache: 32K, L2 cache: 256K, L3 cache: 46080K, CentOS 7, gcc 4.8.3

Time before and after main for() measured with rdtsc or omp_get_wtime functions, trend is very similar.

Is there any problem with thread pooling between sections (teams) in OpenMP ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You always want to minimize the number of parallel regions your code has because I'm pretty sure how the threads are created/spawned/controlled is not defined by OpenMP. They could theoretically be released entirely at the end of every parallel region, therefore ruining performance.

Comment: Also, as-is your code won't compile. You have `int i` utilized in both the inner and outer loops, did you mean to use a different variable?

Comment: I have modified above code for outer loop.